# Maven service used for dependency graph

Tags: java, maven, m2e

Just downloaded the `m2e` Eclipse plugin and love it! I am wondering what web service it uses to resolve all of a project's transitive dependencies.

I *assume* that it works by parsing all of the `<dependency>` elements out of the project `pom.xml`, and uses a service to query Maven for each transitive dependency.

Basically, I'm asking: **how does `m2e` populate the local Maven cache stored at `~/.m2`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin works the same as the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) command line progam mvn.

Assuming your project's POM and Maven settings file does not change the default repository settings Maven will download files from Maven Central

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

So taking a dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven will use the following URL convention (Maven2 repository layout):

```
<Repository URL>/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/<artifactId>-<version>.<packaging>
```

To download 2 files:

1. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.pom
2. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar

The first is the module POM, whose **packaging** element will indicate the file name extension to use when downloading the second file (defaults to "jar").

Finally Maven will recursively read the POM files associated with other dependencies listed in the POM and decide which other modules to download (Dependencies of Dependencies)

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks Mark! Where does Maven download these file to (locally)? I know `m2e` uses `~/.m2`...but what about `mvn` itself?

Comment: The directory "~/.m2/repository" is called the local repository. I like to think of it, as a local cache of files previously downloaded from other Maven repositories. This increases efficiency and enables an off-line Maven build. Looks like both m2e and mvn clients use the same configuration makes sense

Answer (score 3):

By running the normal Maven dependency resolution process; for each dependency it recursively resolves transitive dependencies. The "service" is just a query of the dependencies' POMs from any configured Maven repositories.

Comment: So how do jars actually show up in my `~/.m2` directory? Do they just magically manifest themselves?  At some point, `m2e` has to be sending a signal across a network to a Maven repository saying "hey! send me x" and a download occurs. I'm asking what service this is and how to interface with it.

Comment: @AdamTannon It's generally normal URIs, like `http://` or `file://`, see [Maven repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). There's nothing particularly interesting about it. There are also a ton of Maven-alikes, like Gradle etc., that use the same resolution mechanism, with source readily available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how m2e does it specifically, but you can do the same on the command line using `mvn dependency:tree`. That command supports various output formats: text, dot, graphml, tgf. See [maven dependency plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency%3atree_Mojo).